# Python : Behaviour of send() in generators

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, yield, coroutine

I was experimenting with generators in python 3 and wrote this rather contrived generator :

```
def send_gen():
    print("    send_gen(): will yield 1")
    x = yield 1
    print("    send_gen(): sent in '{}'".format(x))
    # yield  # causes StopIteration when left out


gen = send_gen()
print("yielded {}".format(gen.__next__()))

print("running gen.send()")
gen.send("a string")
```

Output:

```
    send_gen(): will yield 1
yielded 1
running gen.send()
    send_gen(): sent in 'a string'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gen_test.py", line 12, in <module>
    gen.send("a string")
StopIteration
```

So `gen.__next__()` reaches the line `x = yield 1` and yields 1. I thought `x` would be assigned to `None`, then `gen.send()` would look for the *next* `yield` statement because `x = yield 1` is "used", *then* get a `StopIteration`.

Instead, what *seems* to have happened is that `x` gets sent "a string", which is printed, *then* then python attempts to look for the next `yield` and gets a `StopIteration`.

So i try this:

```
def send_gen():
    x = yield 1
    print("    send_gen(): sent in '{}'".format(x))


gen = send_gen()
print("yielded : {}".format(gen.send(None)))
```

Output :

```
yielded : 1
```

But now there's no error. `send()` doesn't appear to have tried to look for the *next* `yield` statement after assigning `x` to `None`.

Why is the behaviour slightly different ? Does this have to do with how I started the generators ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behaviour is *not* different; you never advanced beyond the first `yield` expression in the generator in the second setup. Note that `StopIteration` is **not an error**; it is normal behaviour, the expected signal to be fired whenever a generator has ended. In your second example, you just never reached the end of the generator.

Whenever a generator reaches a `yield` expression, execution pauses *right there*, the expression can't produce anything inside the generator until it is resumed. Either `gen.__next__()` or a `gen.send()` will both resume execution from that point, with the `yield` expression either producing the value passed in by `gen.send()`, or `None`. You could see `gen.__next__()` as a `gen.send(None)` if that helps. The one thing to realise here is that `gen.send()` has `yield` return the sent value **first**, and *then* the generator continues on to the next `yield`.

So, given your first example generator, this happens:

1. `gen = send_gen()` creates the generator object. The code is paused at the very top of the function, nothing is executed.
2. You either call `gen.__next__()` or `gen.send(None)`; the generator commences and executes until the first `yield` expression:

   ```
   print("    send_gen(): will yield 1")
   yield 1
   ```

   and execution now *pauses*. The `gen.__next__()` or `gen.send(None)` calls now return `1`, the value yielded by `yield 1`. Because the generator is now paused, the `x = ...` assignment can't yet take place! That'll only happen when the generator is resumed again.
3. You call `gen.send("a string")` in your first example, don't make *any* call in the second. So for the first example, the generator function is resumed now:

   ```
   x = <return value of the yield expression>  # 'a string' in this case
   print("    send_gen(): sent in '{}'".format(x))
   ```

   and now the function **ends**, so `StopIteration` is raised.

Because you never resumed the generator in your second example, the end of the generator is not reached and no `StopIteration` exception is raised.

Note that because a generator starts at the top of a function, there is no `yield` expression at that point to return whatever you sent with `gen.send()` so a first `gen.send()` value must always be `None` or an exception is raised. It is best to use an explicit `gen.__next__()` (or, rather a `next(gen)` function call) to 'prime' the generator so it'll be paused at the first `yield` expression.

Comment: Ahhh I see. The `x = ...` explanations helped a lot. Thanks !

Comment: Does the execution pauses just before or after the yield assignment? I thought in `x = yield 1`, the `yield 1` and assignment(`=`) were two separate steps. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @nn0p they are two separate steps. `yield 1` pauses, until the generator is resumed, at which point the expression result is assigned to `x`.

Answer (score 3):

The crucial difference here is that you've hit the generator in your first example **twice**, but you hit the generator in your second example only **once**.

When you define a *coroutine*, i.e. a generator which you intend to send arguments into, you'll have to 'prime' it beforehand by advancing to the first yield statement.  Only then can you send in values.  In the first example, you've done this explicitly by calling `gen.__next__()` before attempting to `send`.

In the second example, you also primed it by doing `gen.send(None)` (note that sending in `None` is actually equivalent to calling `gen.__next__()` or `next(gen)`).  But then you didn't try to send in a value a second time, so there was no `StopIteration` in that case.  The generator is just sitting there paused at the yield statement waiting for you to hit it again, and that's also why you didn't yet see the print afterwards.

Another point to note, is that if you had sent anything other than `None` in your second example, there would have been an error:

```
TypeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started generator
```

This is what I was talking about with 'priming' the coroutine.

Answer (score 0):

This is technically a co-routine and not a generator:

1. When we call send_gen(), co-routine object is created
2. When gen.___next____() is called [ We should use next(gen) ], the generator function is called which returns 1 and blocks
3. When gen.send("a string") is called, coroutine woke up and processed the input (here printed "a string")
4. Then the co-routine exited